# ./configure: No such file or directory - build nginx-rtmp-module on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, nginx, rtmp

I'm trying to build nginx-rtmp-module using

```
./configure --add-module=/path/to/nginx-rtmp-module
```

in the Nginx source directory.

However, the terminal prints out " ./configure: No such file or directory" .

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: `/path/to/nginx-rtmp-module` means you need to modify it to the real path of this module...

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I modified the path. I changed it to the location of the module. But it seems the same.  Still print out no such file or directory. Did I miss other things?

Comment: You need to **download** the [module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module), have you?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are trying to execute the script `configure` from the current directory `./`. Either you need to move to the directory where the script is (The nginx install folder that you have downloaded, for example nginx-1.8.1) or you can put in the whole path of the script `/home/username/nginx-1.8.1/configure`

If you didn't understand, just follow this tutorial step by step and everything should be fine ;)
https://blog.100tb.com/how-to-set-up-an-rtmp-server-on-ubuntu-linux-using-nginx

Comment: To clarify. In order to add 3rd party modules, you need to compile nginx from the source. (download it with wget). The pre-built package doesn't allow you to do it. You can find more info on differences between those two methods here https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/installing-nginx-open-source/